# Search using dynamically created anchor href in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, anchor

I want to include a dynamicaly created anchor that links to a search page that displays all users from that company. Users are allowed to be affiliated with more than one company. The information is being pulled from a mysql database example:

John Doe is affiliated with:

- Pepsi Company
- Cold Drinks Inc Company
- Sports Drinks Company

John Doe is affiliated with:

```
<a href="search/useraffiliation1"> Pespi Company</a>
<a href="search/useraffiliation2"> Cold Drinks Inc Company</a>
<a href="search/useraffiliation3"> Sports Drinks Company</a>
```

1.Whats the best way to go about doing this.

2.Whats the best way to structure my database. Should I use a single column for each affiliation or put all the affiliations in one.

Comment: I`d use 3 tables (users, x_user_affiliations, companies)

Comment: also I would recomment you think on a link structure like: `search/user/{user_id}/affiliations` and maybe `search/affiliation/{affiliation_id}`

Comment: Thanks a million, you saved me a lot of headaches! I understand the 3 tables structure, but could you explain the structure in more detail please. Thanks so much! For instance how would you structure each table for users, user affiliations, and affiliations!

Comment: another note, the companies are being submitted by users

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: I just realized that I was responding to the comments and didn't really answer your original question, so I updated my examples below.*

If you are using Laravel and artisan fully to build your database and track migrations, here is what you need to do for the **3 tables**.  You want the affiliations table to hold the id of the user and the id of the company.

First, create 3 database migrations in your command line:

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --table="users"
php artisan make:migration create_companies_table --table="companies"
php artisan make:migration create_affiliations_table --table="affiliations"
```

You will now have 3 migration files in your /database/migrations folder.

The files will look like this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableUsers extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password', 60);
            //more fields @see https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-columns
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

--

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableCompanies extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('companies', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name', 100);
            //more fields @see https://laravel.com/docs/master/migrations#creating-columns
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('companies');
    }
}
```

--

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTableAffiliations extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('affiliations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->primary(['user_id', 'company_id']);
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('affiliations');
    }
}
```

Now run artisan one more time in your console to create the tables.

```
php artisan migrate
```

You have several options at this point when you query your database.  For example, a raw SQL query might look like:

```
SELECT c.* FROM affiliations a JOIN companies c ON (a.company_id=c.id) WHERE a.user_id=1;
```

or

```
SELECT u.* FROM affiliations a JOIN users u ON (a.user_id=u.id) WHERE a.company_id=1;
```

However, it's probably better to use eloquent models since you are using Laravel.  I like to create Db models in my App/Db folder.  For example, this is what the /App/Db/Companies.php may look like.

```
<?php 

namespace App\Db;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Companies extends Model {

    use SoftDeletes;

    public function affiliations() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Db\Affiliations', 'company_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

THIS IS JUST AN EXAMPLE, AND NOT TESTED.

Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

You would make your other Db table models (Affiliations & Users) too, and in your application, a query might look like this:

```
class CompanyController extends Controller {

    public function search($id) {
        $company = Companies::find($id);
        $company->load('affiliations.users');

        foreach ($company->affiliation as $aff) {
            echo $aff->user->name;
        }       
    }
}
```

You could switch that around too where you find the users that have an affiliation with that company id.  More on querying relations: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations

There are several ways to achieve your desired result, so really read up on those eloquent relationships!  It seems like a lot of work for something so simple but when you are building larger applications it's very handy.

Pertaining to your original question, the route for this could look like:

```
Route::get('/search/company/{id}', 'CompanyController@search');
```